# Plink still prints keyboard interactive prompts with -batch option

Tags: node.js, ssh, putty, child-process, plink

I'm building a abstraction layer on top of node.js 'child_process' to enable a system to invoke a CLI tool either locally or remotely using the same wrapper, so that I can invoke the CLI tools using the same code, regardless of the machine I'm in.

I've done something similar using Java + JSch in the past, and now I'm trying to do the same for JavaScript + node.js.

For Windows hosts, I'm using PLink to invoke the remote CLI command. What I'm doing is the following:

```
spawn(args)
{
    const mode = this._mode;
    const config = this._config;

    var actualCommand;
    var actualArgs;
    if (mode == MODE_LOCAL)
    {
        // just use plain child_process.spawn...
        actualCommand = args[0];
        actualArgs = args.slice(1);
    }
    else if (mode == MODE_REMOTE)
    {
        if (process.platform == "win32")
        {
            // for Windows machines, use PLink
            // ./win/plink -batch -ssh <USER>@<HOST> -pw <PASSWORD> <COMMAND...>
            const sep = require("path").sep;
            actualCommand = __dirname + sep + "win" + sep + "plink";
            actualArgs = [ "-batch", "-ssh", config.username + "@" + config.host, "-pw", config.password ].concat(args);
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO use ssh for Linux and Mac
            throw "Not supported yet";
        }
    }
    return child_process.spawn(actualCommand, actualArgs);
}
```

I don't want to use a SSH node module, that's why I'm going for PLink. I must do this without using an external library, since doing that would require me to get internal clearance for that library, and this would jeopardize our project schedule.

Once I spawn the process, I do the following:

```
const spawner = new Spawner().remote({ host: "...", username: "...", password: "..." });
const ls = spawner.spawn( [ 'ls', '-ll' ] );

ls.stdout.on( 'data', data => {
    console.log( `stdout: ${data}` );
} );

ls.stderr.on( 'data', data => {
    console.log( `stderr: ${data}` );
} );

ls.on( 'close', code => {
    console.log( `child process exited with code ${code}` );
} );
```

Even though I add the "-batch" argument to PLink, it still prints to STDERR information related to the server interaction:

```
stderr: Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
stderr: End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
```

Since I'm using PLink in the batch mode, it should not do interactive prompts. The 'batch' option prevents PLink from blockin the CLI with interactive prompts alright, but I'm still getting interaction-related information to STDERR. Is there a way to get *completely* rid of keyboard-interactive prints while using PLink?

Comment: I have to parse the CLI output of the process, that includes STDOUT and STDERR. The fact that PLink prints something in the STDERR means I have to either: 1) Filter out the PLink output in the high-level code (which should not have to care on whether the process is run locally or remotely. 2) Filter out PLink output in the low-level code, meaning I have to wrap it in my class.Either way, this would not be needed if I could just prevent PLink from printing its interactive prompts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent Plink from printing the prompts.

And no one claims that the `-batch` switch does that. The switch only prevents Plink from asking user to answer the prompts.

Also, there are definitely other "stderr" output that Plink can print.

If you want to have a full control over the output, you will have to use an SSH library, instead of running an external SSH client.